# I can't run matplotlib on python3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plotttt

def simular (N):

  Nd=N
  c=0

  while Nd>(N/2-1):
      r=random.uniform(0,1)

      if r<Nd/float(N):
         Nd=Nd-1

      else:
         Nd=Nd+1

      c+=1

  return c

def main ():

   Nmax=400
   repeticiones=100

   x=[]
   y=[]

   for j in range (2,Nmax):

       promedio=0

       for i in range (0,repeticiones):
           promedio+=simular(j)

       y.append(promedio/repeticiones)
       x.append(j)

   plotttt.plot (x,y,"bo")
   plotttt.show()

main()
```

But when I try to run in through terminal the next error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1519, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    import pyparsing
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 65, in <module>
    import string.ascii_lowercase
ImportError: No module named 'string.ascii_lowercase'; string is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simulacion.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plotttt
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    raise ImportError("matplotlib requires pyparsing")
ImportError: matplotlib requires pyparsing
Vicente-Gomezs-MacBook-Pro:Python Vicente$
```

However no problem occurs when I run it on IDLE.  Ideas?

Comment: You have to install `pyparsing` as the error says.  I am surprised that it did not get installed when you install matplotlib.

Comment: I did install pyparsing.

Comment: sorry, missed the last line.  The issue is probably you are not running the version of python that you installed mpl with.